# Latex table alignment problem with multicolumn and multirow

Tags: latex

How can I align this table. It does not algin column two and three at center.

[image: Table]

I am using following code:

```
    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Comparison with the hybrid architecture}
  \label{tab:comparison}
  \begin{center} 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Average Episode Reward for 10 Runs (deviation)}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Disturbance Magnitude}}            \\
\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\textit{Architecture}}} 
& 65\%                       & 70\%                       \\ \hline
PID                                                         & -17.71                     & -23.54                        \\
CoL-DRL                                                      & -2.58                      & -12.25                        \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{9AFF99} CoL-DRPRL                            & -1.85                      & -6.25                         \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Please add missing parts to your code so we can compile and see the result. You should include all packages and any non-standard document class. If I add missing preamble and just the standard document class, everything works as expected.